# Regular expression to split up city, state

Tags: regex, r

I have a list of city, state data in a data frame. *I need to extract only the state abbreviation and store into a new variable* column called `state`. From visual inspection it looks like the state is always the last 2 characters in the string and they are both capitalized. The city, state data looks like the following:

```
test <- c("Anchorage, AK", "New York City, NY", "Some Place, Another Place, LA")
```

I tried the following

```
pattern <- "[, (A-Z){2}]"
strsplit(test, pattern)
```

The output was:

```
[[1]]
[1] "Anchorage, "

[[2]]
[1] "New York City, "

[[3]]
[1] "Some Place, Another Place, "
```

EDI:
I used another regular expresson:

```
pattern2 <- "([a-z, ])"
sp <- strsplit(test, pattern2)
```

I get these results:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "A"  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "AK"

[[2]]
 [1] "N"  ""   ""   "Y"  ""   ""   ""   "C"  ""   ""   ""   ""   "NY"

[[3]]
 [1] "S"  ""   ""   ""   "P"  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "A"  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   ""  
[18] "P"  ""   ""   ""   ""   ""   "LA"
```

So, the abbreviation is there, but when I try to extract using `sapply()`, I am not sure how to get the last element of a list.  I know how to get the first:

```
sapply(sp, "[[", 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you really need a regular expression here. If you always just want the last two characters of the string, just use

```
substring(test, nchar(test)-1, nchar(test))
[1] "AK" "NY" "LA"
```

If you really insist on a regular expression, at least consider using `regexec` rather than `strsplit` since you're not really interested in splitting, you only want to extract the state.

```
m <- regexec("[A-Z]+$", test)
unlist(regmatches(test,m))
# [1] "AK" "NY" "LA"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can work:

```
regmatches(test, gregexpr("(?<=[,][\\s+])([A-Z]{2})", test, perl = TRUE))

## [[1]]
## [1] "AK"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "NY"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "LA"
```

**Explanation** compliments of: http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl

```
(?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
  [,]                      any character of: ','
  [\\s+]                    any character of: whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '+'
)                        end of look-behind
(                        group and capture to \1:
  [A-Z]{2}                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z' (2 times)
)                        end of \1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
tt = strsplit(test, ', ')

tt
[[1]]
[1] "Anchorage" "AK"      

[[2]]
[1] "New York City" "NY"          

[[3]]
[1] "Some Place"     "Another Place" "LA"           


z = list()

for(i in tt) z[length(z)+1] = i[length(i)]


z
[[1]]
[1] "AK"

[[2]]
[1] "NY"

[[3]]
[1] "LA"
```

Comment: Something like `sapply(strsplit(test,", "),tail,1)` would be simpler if you wanted to go this route. `substr` is probably still preferable regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I think you understood reversely the meaning of '[]' and '()'. '()' means to match a group of characters; '[]' means to match any one character from a class. What you need is

"(, [A-Z]{2})".

Answer (score 0):

```
 library(stringr)
 str_extract(test, perl('[A-Z]+(?=\\b$)'))
 #[1] "AK" "NY" "LA"
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a regex for the same

**Regex**

```
(?'state'\w{2})(?=")
```

**Test String**

```
"Anchorage, AK", "New York City, NY", "Some Place, Another Place, LA"
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  - state    [12-14] `AK`
- MATCH 2

  - state    [33-35] `NY`
- MATCH 3

  - state    [66-68] `LA`

**[live demo here](http://regex101.com/r/wL5iS3/1)**

you may remove the named capture to make it smaller if required

eg

```
(\w{2})(?=")
```